# read entire text file into one-dimensional array

Tags: c, file-io, io

I want to read a text file including a string of minimum length 0 and maximum length 1024.Then, I want to put it into an array to process the characters of that string. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the maximum length you can just declare an array of the appropriate size and use `fread` to read the string.

```
FILE* theFilePointer = ...;
char text[1024];
fread(text, sizeof(char), 1024, theFilePointer);
```

Comment: @R.. yes you're correct. Been too long since i've done C I/O. Making the easy mistakes

Comment: I think it is not an efficient way. If the string length is 10, it is not good to use an array with 1024 elements. I am looking to find a better way.

Comment: @sepanta there are trade offs both ways. If you start with a small buffer and it's a long string then you will waste time resizing buffers to fit the new size and re-doing the I/O calls to get the remaining text.  It depends on which resource is more important to your app: space or time.

Comment: How is it not efficient? If there's a max size that's not huge, the most efficient solution is always using a fixed-size automatic (stack) array. Dynamic allocation will be much slower and generally lead to more memory usage, and VLA results in overhead accessing local variables because the distance from the stack pointer to local vars may not be constant.

Comment: And yes, that's not even considering the (relatively HUGE) cost of resizing the buffer and performing multiple small reads if your first guess about the size was too small.

Comment: Actually time is the most important thing in my program. I am working on string matching problem. I want to read the string in the file as my pattern and search the pattern in the text. The pattern can be included any type of characters and its minimum and maximum length is 1 and 1024, respectively. Do you think that it is the efficient way to be used in my program?

Comment: @sepanta if time is the critical component and you know the max size and it's a small number like `1024` then i would definitely start with this approach. Allocation of a buffer on the stack is **much** faster than the heap (especially if you start small and have to reallocate and re-read for a file with larger contents).

Answer (score 2):

```
char buf[1025];
size_t len = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf - 1, f);
buf[len] = 0;
```

Comment: I believe you inverted the size parameters. It should be size of element, then size of buffer

Comment: The order does not matter. Either way the function reads `size*nelems` bytes into consecutive entries of the pointed-to `unsigned char` array (the representation of the object).

Comment: Never mind; you are of course right since I'm using the return value which will be in elements, not bytes. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: size_t len = fread(buf, 1, (sizeof( buf)) - 1, f);  // make sure you handle errors if len is 0 and maybe less than nelems * bufsize

Comment: Fixed the -1 issue. Zero-length read is handled; if you want to treat error and other zero-length read differently you could of course do so with `ferror` but it's not necessarily needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[1025];
int i=read(fd,buf,1024);
if (i>=0) buf[i]=0;
```